# Boxes in grid too tall

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to create a grid of squares where some blocks are double the size of others and some others are double the width, but the same height.

This [Codepen](https://codepen.io/tyssen/pen/vYQzqbw) illustrates what I'm trying to do. The fourth and fifth blocks should be double the width, but only one row high. But instead, they're two rows high.

**HTML**

```
<div class="grid">
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.grid>div:nth-child(1),
.grid>div:nth-child(8) {
  grid-row: auto / span 2;
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}
.grid>div:nth-child(4),
.grid>div:nth-child(5){
  grid-column: auto / span 2;
}
```

I'm not telling those blocks to span two rows so I don't understand why they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not telling those blocks to span two rows so I don't understand
> why they are.

They are not spanning two rows. The image inside the grid cell has an aspect ratio of 1-to-1, therefore filling only half of some cells (this can be seen in your browser's Developer Tools.)

The first example illustrates this with:

```
.grid div {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```css
.grid div {
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.grid>div:nth-child(1),
.grid>div:nth-child(8) {
  grid-row-start: span 2;
  grid-column-start: span 2;
}
.grid>div:nth-child(4),
.grid>div:nth-child(5){
  grid-column-start: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

The second example illustrates this with:

```
img {
   height: 100%;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid>div:nth-child(1),
.grid>div:nth-child(8) {
  grid-row-start: span 2;
  grid-column-start: span 2;
}
.grid>div:nth-child(4),
.grid>div:nth-child(5){
  grid-column-start: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://dummyimage.com/436x436/000/fff.png" alt=""></div>
</div>
```